# Modules and submodules files fully asynchronous loading

Tags: jquery, performance, asynchronous, module, getscript

I would like to have a fully asynchronous method for loading modules' files on the client side, without the need of extra tools, such as requireJS. My module template follows the ["Revealing module pattern" template](https://medium.com/@tkssharma/javascript-module-pattern-b4b5012ada9f).

In my file `root.js` I have

```js
root = (function(thisModule){

  //I'm stuck here, I know I need to add the already 
  //existent properties of thisModule into here 
  //when child.js is loaded first

  function A(){...}
  function B(){...} //public method

  return{
     B:B
  };

})(root || {});
```

In my file `child.js` I have

```js
root = root || {};
root.child = (function(){

  function C(){...}     
  function D(){...}  //public methods

  return{
     D:D
  };

})();
```

How do I rewrite the first module in `root.js` **such that the files' loading order is irrelevant**? That is, the following code will never throw an exception.

```
$.when($.getScript("root.js"), $.getScript("child.js")).done(function(){
   root.B;
   root.child.D;
});
```

Comment: So you want to be able to access `root.B` and `root.child.D` after both scripts are loaded, is that it?

Comment: I think promises are the way to go here. But you say you don't want to do that. Are you okay with the idea of polling until you see it load? Why the opposition to promises?

Comment: @mccambridge do you mean promises in the `getScript`? I want the loading of files to be fully async.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yes, and independently of file loading order. Is it possible?

Comment: @CertainPerformance my problem is that when `child.js` loads first, `root.child` gets erased by the loading of `root.js`

Comment: Promises are async. ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: @mccambridge yes, I know :) but I want to fully asynchronously load all the files independent of loading order. If you make a promise or callback, waiting for a file to be loaded to load the next file, you're indeed making the loading synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest tweak to your code would be to preserve the contents of `thisModule` - just assign to the `B` property of `thisModule` and then return `thisModule` instead of returning only `{ B:B }`:

```
var root = (function(thisModule){
  function A(){ }
  function B(){ } //public method
  thisModule.B = B;
  return thisModule;
})(root || {});
```

If `root` is meant to be global, then it might be a bit clearer if you explicitly refer to `window.root`, otherwise you might encounter bugs if you accidentally put that snippet somewhere other than at the top level:

```
window.root = (function(thisModule){ ...
```

As a side note, assuming your build process uses Babel (which any serious project should), you can consider using shorthand properties to reduce syntax noise, eg:

```
return{ D };
```

rather than

```
return{ D: D };
```

which could be helpful if the method names are long - less syntax noise.

Comment: thanks a lot, really! My project uses `uglify-js` to compact the js code.

Comment: I rewrote my question to clarify exactly what was my point, I hope it is ok for you. Anyway you have already given the solution.